Struggling with developing code for an online learning using river library with ARFRegressor algorithm
I have split the data but struggling to write the code for training the model and saving the model in particular directory using pickle for future use. Any suggestions on how to proceed?
# Splitting data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

from river import evaluate
from river import forest
from river import metrics
from river import preprocessing

model = (
    preprocessing.StandardScaler() |
    forest.ARFRegressor(seed=42)
)
metric = metrics.MAE()

# Evaluate the model on the testing set
mae = evaluate.progressive_val_score(X_test, y_test, model, metric)
print(f'MAE on the test set: {mae}')


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
